# error with eclipse Luna 4.4.1 and tomcat8 and java7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have windows 7 and tomcat 8 and eclipse Luna 4.4.1 and i have create a web application but i am not able to deploy this web application it is showing error. I have given below the stack trace from the tomcat startup logs: Please help me

```
Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.15


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 2 2014 19:25:20 UTC


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.15.0


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1

Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JAVA_HOME:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_25-b18


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Demo\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log


INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\Demo\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\Demo\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;D:\eclipse;;.


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1369 ms


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.15


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor D:\Demo\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\DemoPro.xml


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin


WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DemoPro' did not find a matching property.


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor D:\Demo\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\DemoPro.xml has finished in 126 ms


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]


Dec 01, 2014 5:25:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 856 ms
```

Comment: There is no error in these logs

Comment: Where is the error? Probably you missed error stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

there isnt any error !!!

**Server startup in 856 ms** its a simple notification, this isnt an error log !!!!

Dont forget to add your project to the server (Right click on the server -> add -> add your project), do restart to the server than run your project on the server.

I hope it will help you, best regards !